# How do I use chrome-types in an Angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm starting to learn Chrome Extension development using angular and would like to use [chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) package but I am having great difficulty import/using it.

My IDE, IntelliJ and the build complain that `chrome-types/index.d.ts' is not a module.`. I have done the following:

1. `npm i chrome-types`
2. Tried including `"types": ["chrome-types"]` under `compilerOptions` of `tsconfig.json`
3. Tried including `"typeRoots": ["chrome-types]` under `compilerOptions` of `tsconfig.json`
4. Included `import * as chromeTypes from 'chrome-types';`

None of the above resolves the issue.

How am I mean to use `chrome-types` in Angular?

Comment: there shouldn't be `import * as chromeTypes from 'chrome-types';`  in your code

Comment: @Andrei I removed that import but to get it to work I had to put the types in `tsconfig.app.json` and NOT `tsconfig.json`. That doesn't make sense to me as it should work either way?

Comment: it should work either way. you need several tsconfigs in case you have different groups of files that should work a little bit differently. default groups are "app" and "spec". you don't want typescript to think you have access to global `descrive` , `it` and other testing utils for your normal application  files